# Replacing Primary SMTP Address

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, ems

I have the following, working no problem.

```
Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $username -RemoteRoutingAddress($username+'@MYORG365.mail.onmicrosoft.com') 

sleep 30

Get-RemoteMailbox $username|Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true

sleep 5

Get-RemoteMailbox $username|Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$false

sleep 5

Get-RemoteMailbox $username|Set-RemoteMailbox -PrimarySmtpAddress($username+'@MYORG.com')
```

What this script does, it adds an additional "address@MYR.ORG.COM" smtp to the mailbox that was just created for $username and set is as the primary smtp.

What i am trying to do next is either, EDIT the existing primary smtp , and set it like above.
Or DELETE, the current primary smtp and add a NEW primary smtp instead of above, so that eventually i will end up only with a single SMTP / PRIMARY-SMTP for this new mailbox.

Your help is mostly appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: As an aside: It's best to avoid pseudo method syntax such as `-PrimarySmtpAddress($username+'@MYORG.com')`. Use `-PrimarySmtpAddress ($username+'@MYORG.com')` - the space makes it clear that the result of the expression (`(...)`) is being passed as a - normally _whitespace-separated_ - argument to the `-PrimarySmtpAddress` parameter, in [argument-parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing)